# Does lubridate have a function similar to the yearmon function of zoo?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am dealing with a data.frame with a month variable that only has year and month component. Part of my data is as below:

```
     month         DIV  MKTP
1  1941-12 0.005752218 -4.87
2  1942-01 0.005767111  0.79
3  1942-02 0.005781771 -2.46
4  1942-03 0.005859665 -6.58
5  1942-04 0.005906924 -4.37
6  1942-05 0.005890041  5.94
7  1942-06 0.005941640  2.69
8  1942-07 0.005962464  3.51
9  1942-08 0.005936732  1.80
10 1942-09 0.006007593  2.61
```

I would like to transform the month variable to a yearmon format for subseting purpose. My code is as below:

```
require(zoo,dplyr)
  df %>%
  mutate(month = as.yearmon(month)) %>%
  filter(month >= as.yearmon("1942-3") & month <= as.yearmon("1942-8"))
```

I would like to know if lubridate package has a similar function to yearmon that could take input of a combination of year and month.

Comment: I just modified my code to make it suitable for the example

Comment: Apparently pkg:lubridate now has a `my` function to coerce a month-year character argument to first of the month Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `filter` using `year`, `month` functions after converting to `Date` class with `ymd`

```
library(tidyverse) 
df %>% 
   mutate(date = ymd(paste0(month, "-01"))) %>% 
   filter(year(date)>= 1942, month(date)>3, month(date)<=8, year(date) < 1943) %>%
   select(-date)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I want!

Comment: You could also use `floor_date(date, "months")` to end up with a genuine date still like "1942-03-01". I've actually found this more useful than doing `zoo::yearmon(date)` and then converting back to a date. The `floor_date()` also allows you to adjust the interval to Year, Quarter, Month, etc.

Answer (score 7):

[Here are lubridate's functions](https://rdrr.io/cran/lubridate/) and the answer is no, because `lubridate` is for dealing with dates and dates have days. You could assume that the day is 01 and convert to a date format using `ymd` or just stick with `zoo::yearmon`.

Comment: Or use anytime::anydate("1941-12"), which also assumes day = 1

Comment: If so, how do you explain the `yq()` function...?

Comment: I explain it as (1) hidden away in the `ymd` documentation and (2) parsing year-quarter, not year-month.