# Convert data type character to date in R

Tags: r, types

I tried to convert data type of the column but the result showing nothing.

I was trying to convert data type of this column
 `$ Date     : chr  "01/2004" "02/2004" "03/2004" "04/2004" ...`

Here's my code

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%Y"))
```

And this is the result
 `$ Date     : Date, format: NA NA NA ...`

The column I tried to convert data type doesn't contain date(it only has month and year), can it be a problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533582/does-lubridate-have-a-function-similar-to-the-yearmon-function-of-zoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates in R must have the day attribute. If you don't mind assuming the day is the first of each month, you can use the `lubridate` package: `lubridate::my(Date)`. For example, `lubridate::my("01/2004")` returns a Date object representing Jan. 1, 2004.

Answer (score 2):

Simply prefix with an arbitrary day, e.g. `"01"` using `paste0`.

```
> as.Date(paste0('01/', x), '%d/%m/%Y')
[1] "2004-01-01" "2004-02-01" "2004-03-01" "2004-04-01"
```

---

*Data:*

```
> x <- c("01/2004", "02/2004", "03/2004", "04/2004")
```